# Javascript sorting vs .sort()

Tags: javascript, sorting

I came across this question:.
Sort an array using javascript.
My ans: .sort() method, the other person asked me to use the bubble sort algorithm and sort it.
Does that make any difference?

Comment: Yes it makes a difference. We don't know who "the other person" is but I would stay away from him or her and definitely don't ingest any substances they offer you.

Comment: It makes so much difference that any possible answer here would be too broad. There are many different sorting algorithms, and they are often the very first thing you learn about in an algorithms class. (Ironically, you often learn them first, before they teach you about the datatypes that make them different.)

Comment: This was an array of integers, what would be the most efficient to sort that out vs the inbuilt .sort function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a *practical* matter, you are much better off using the built-in sort, which is much more efficient than a bubble sort, implemented in a much faster language than Javascript, and programmed by someone better at it than you.

As an academic assignment, though, it's a good one.  You should write your own bubble sort and use the built-in to compare it for accuracy and speed.

Comment: @Malvolio It might be worth being a little more explicit that comparing vs the native for speed isn't the same as comparing two different algorithms, if you want to compare two algorithms, you should write both and compare those.

Comment: @PaulS. -- yes, the only information you would really acquire from the comparison I proposed would be an answer to the question, "Why, as a practical matter, should you never use a Javascript bubble-sort?"  It might also be interesting to find out the sort your browser uses, write a Javascript version of _that_, and see how much of the difference come from algorithm and how much from language.

Comment: @Malvolio when you pass a comparator into `sort` in _Chrome_ I think it does an insert sort `(ar = [3, 1, 2, 0]).sort(function (a, b) {console.log(ar.join(), a, b); return a >= b;});`

Comment: @PaulS. -- it wouldn't surprise me if sort() used an insertion sort for small lists and something more sophisticated for anything larger.